# Reduce the Xcode Simulator (Retina 4 inch)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, retina-display

I'm using macbook Air and using the iphone Simulator. I changed it to Retina 4 inch, and the screen of the simulator become so big! is there a way to reduce the size?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can scale it with the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>: 100%
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>: 75%
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>: 50%
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>: 33%
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>: 25%

Or in iOS Simulator: `Window > Scale > ...`

Comment: I can see that, but ..i think its just the macbook air...the ipad simulator is still way too big at 50%

Comment: I would consider a secondary screen then ;)

Comment: Thanks! This was a great help, but I can understand your problem, OP. I have a 22" external display and 4" Retina iPhone takes up about 80% of vertical space on it at 50%.

Comment: @JustAnotherCoder Yes, The window is not sizable, but can be scaled by a shortcut. I sometimes does not understand why people can live with MacOS.

Comment: Actually, iOS8 simulator is going to have resizable devices as indicated in http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/06/iphone-6-hint-ios-simulator.html in order to let us define custom screen sizes

Answer (score 10):

The iOS Simulator's Window menu has an option to display the simulator at 50%, 75%, or 100%. Try one of the smaller values to make it fit.

Answer (score 2):

Now It's more flexible with Xcode 9-Simulator.

You can pick & drag any corner or simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

[image]

There are several other ways also, to scale your simulator.

**Using Terminal Command**

Follow these steps to scale simulator using terminal commands

1. Close/Quit simulator. (if open)
2. Open `Terminal` app (using Spotlight search, Press `⌘ + SPACE` to open spotlight search)
3. Copy following text and paste it next to terminal cursor.

`defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.3"`

4. Open 'Simulator' (Run your iOS project using Xcode).

You will find simulator scale update.

**Simulator scale options from Xcode Menu**:

> Menubar  >>  Window  >>  Scale  >>  "Here available options for simulator scaling"

Here is ref snapshot:
[image]